# How to modify autogenerated Django models?

Tags: django, django-models, python-3.5

I am using **django 1.11**. I have generated `models.py` using `inspectdb`.
I followed `makemigrations` and `migrate`, which was successfully done. 
By default after `inspectdb`, `managed` is set to `False`, which I've changed to `True` (or can be removed). 
It looked something like this, before making the change:

```
class TableName(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    field_one = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    field_two = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    field_three = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    field_four = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'table_name'
```

After the manual change in `models.py` :

```
class TableName(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    field_one = models.ForeignKey(TableXYZ, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field_two = models.ForeignKey(TableABC,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field_three = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    field_four = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'table_name'
```

Now when i followed `makemigrations` and `migrate`, no changes were detected or applied. I want the changes to reflect, but it is not detecting any change in models. This doesn't happen when we manually write the models, as it is happening when generated with `inspectdb`. Please help.

Comment: If there is no data in table just drop the table and do migrations

Comment: If your just changing managed you shouldn't need to perform a migration. Migrations are only needed when you are making database changes. Have you checked that your model is being saved correctly after changing managed to True?

Comment: I found the issue, forgot the mention app in `installed_apps`. The project level migrations then conflicted with the app level migrations. Have sorted it out.